# Mixture distribution fitting for latent variable analysis

Tags: distributions, factor-analysis, mixture-distribution, population, latent-variable

Are there any **analytic approaches** to using *mixture distribution fitting* for *latent variable analysis*? I'm specifically interested in existing approaches to determining whether mixture components indicate a presence of *sub-populations* OR *effect(s)* from underlying *factor(s)*. References to relevant key *papers*, *tutorials*, *guidelines*, *examples* and `R` *packages* are additionally welcome.

P.S. This question implies the subsequent planned use of standard social sciences *quantitative multivariate methods*, such as *factor analysis* (`EFA` and `CFA`), in a target research study.